# I need this :nth:child equations

Tags: css

I have searched google and know how to write equations for nth:child, but I can not select the following child. I need to select 5th, 9th, 13th, 17th, ...

Do you know an equations for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:nth-child(4n+5)
```

That should work

Comment: And for users who want to know how these nth-child equations works, check this page http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/